# Question on sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sequence S had 20 numbers. Jan re- placed each number in S with its rank (smallest to largest) within S: 1 for smallest, 2 for second smallest, etc. The sum of Jan's first 5 numbers was 66. Ann replaced each number in S with its rank (largest to smallest) within S: 1 for largest,..., 20 for smallest. What was the sum of Ann's first 5 numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1,...a_{20}$ represent the numbers in the sequence. For $a_1,...,a_5$, Jan's ranking will be $j_1,...,j_5$. This means that for each $a_i$, $j_i - 1$ numbers will be ranked below $a_i$. Let $k_1,...k_5$ represent Ann's rankings for $a_1,...,a_5$. For Ann, this means for each $a_i$, $k_i - 1$ numbers will be ranked above $a_i$. We know there are $20$ total numbers, so $(j_i - 1) + (k_i - 1) + 1 = 20$. This means that $j_i + k_i = 21$ for all $i$. Since we are only looking at the first $5$ numbers, this means the sum of the total will be $105$, so Ann's sum will be $105 - 66 = 39$